# Is position(substring in string) in PostgreSQL case sensitive

Tags: postgresql

If not, I think `lower(string)` could be used to have a case insensitive comparison, but I'm not sure if I need that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is case-sensitive.

```
psql (9.1.4)

postgres=> select position('f' in 'foo');
 position
----------
        1
(1 row)


Time: 200,830 ms
postgres=> select position('F' in 'foo');
 position
----------
        0
(1 row)


Time: 0,327 ms
postgres=>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is case sensitive in Postgres.